# Get running process' full command-line in one line string with Powershell

Tags: powershell, win32-process, get-wmiobject

I'm trying to find a way to get a process' full command line in one string to detect if a java application is already running. The program allows for multiple instances, but I want to prevent opening more than one instance. The output of the command adds 4 return carriages which I would like to remove. Here's the what I used:

`$processRunning = Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter "name= 'javaw.exe'" | select -ExpandProperty CommandLine`

The problem I'm having is that the line above adds return carriages because the command line is very long.
I've tried formating it differently with Format-Table and Format-List. 
I've also tried **`` -replace "`r", "" ``** and **`| Out-String -Width 2048`**.

I want to match the result like so:

`$startProcess = ([wmiclass]"win32_process").Create($processToStart)
if ($processRunning -like $commandLine ) 
{ 
    Write-Output "Program is already running"

}
else
{
    Write-Output "Starting Process"
    $startProcess
    Wait-Process -Id $startProcess.ProcessId
}`

The **`Wait-Process`** command doesn't work because apparently **`$startProcess.ProcessId`** is empty or null.

Thank you

Comment: That result is returning as an array. You will need to join the array entries into a string if you want a single line.

Comment: "The problem I'm having is that the line above adds return carriages" - what gives you the impression that the string contains embedded carriage returns?

Comment: @Bill_Stewart Maybe it's not the right way to verify that but I copied-pasted the output from the console to a text file and it contained carriage returns. And the `if ($processRunning -like $starTeamCommandLine )` is never true even though I  know that $processRunning contains $CommandLine

Comment: @Jason I already tried -join "`r" and it didn't work. Maybe I just used it wrong...?

Comment: You are correct; that's not the right way to verify.